# My site's top banner and background images only show up in IE and not in FF. What's wrong?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser, dreamweaver

Hey thanks if you can help, I've been learning as I go with this, my first site, and now I'm stumped.

http://www.enviro-bridge.ca

It seems I've changed something recently that prevents FF and Crome from recognizing the template's images. I can't figure out what has happened. And it looks fine in IE8!

If you need more info let me know.

Comment: Take a look at the validator and fix all the errors you see. XHTML can be a tricky doctype to work with. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.enviro-bridge.ca%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0):

The url's to the banner images are local to your machine. So on any other computer the site will not work even in IE. Make the urls relative to your site's ROOT path and it should work if you have thos images on your server that is

```
background-image: url(file://///sanders/web/envirobridge/Publish/images/banner_bkgd.jpg);
```

should be something like:

```
background-image: url(/images/banner_bkgd.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something o do with your css file here:

```
background-image: url(file://///sanders/web/envirobridge/Publish/images/banner_bkgd.jpg);
```

Can you do something different with that url?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute paths for images, links, etc.

In your CSS, you're using absolute paths, like this:

```
file://///sanders/web/envirobridge/Publish/images/content_bkgd_tile.jpg
```

Use relative paths.